# Join on following queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing these two queries.

1.

```
select widget_uid,param_value as campaign_name
from widget_config_value
where widget_uid in (select widget_uid
                     from widget_config_value
                     where param_name="active"
                           and param_value="1"
                           and widget_uid in (select widget_uid
                                              from partner_widget
                                              where partner_uid=4)
                    )
       and param_name="widgetCampaignName";
```

2.

```
select widget_uid,param_value as campaign_type
from widget_config_value
where widget_uid in (select widget_uid
                     from widget_config_value
                     where param_name="active"
                           and param_value="1"
                           and widget_uid in (select widget_uid
                                              from partner_widget
                                              where partner_uid=4)
                    )
      and  param_name="widgetType";
```

How can i join this on widget_uid?? so, i can get results for common widget_uid's??

or Is there any way to improve above query??

Comment: Those two queried seems exactly the same except param_name? Can't this work "param_name IN('widgetCampaignName','widgetType')"

Comment: Jon? As in [Jon Skeet][http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet]? :P

Comment: @Jonas-param name is different for widgetcampaignname and widgettype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it in the following way -

```
select widget_uid, campaign_name, campaign_type from
(select widget_uid,param_value as campaign_name from widget_config_value 
where widget_uid in 
(select widget_uid from widget_config_value 
where param_name="active" 
and param_value="1" 
and widget_uid in (select widget_uid from partner_widget where partner_uid=4)) 
and param_name="widgetCampaignName") tbl1,
(select widget_uid,param_value as campaign_type 
from widget_config_value 
where widget_uid in 
(select widget_uid 
from widget_config_value 
where param_name="active" 
and param_value="1" 
and widget_uid in (select widget_uid from partner_widget where partner_uid=4)) 
and param_name="widgetType") tbl2
where tbl1.widget_uid = tbl2.widget_uid;
```

Comment: it looks good...but still have one problem, widget_uid is ambiguous

Comment: Hi, try `tbl1.widget_uid` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I think query won't work because it is impossible that

```
param_name="active" and param_name="widgetCampaignName"
```

in the same time. Also query no. 2

Look at your query

```
select 
    widget_uid,param_value as campaign_name 
from widget_config_value
where 
    widget_uid in (
        select widget_uid 
        from 
            widget_config_value 
        where 
            param_name="active" and 
            param_value="1" and 
            widget_uid in (
                select widget_uid 
                from partner_widget 
                where partner_uid=4)
            ) and
     param_name="widgetCampaignName";
```

In this part

```
select widget_uid 
        from 
            widget_config_value 
        where 
            param_name="active" and 
            param_value="1" and 
            widget_uid in (
                select widget_uid 
                from partner_widget 
                where partner_uid=4)
            )
```

give you `widget_config_value` data that is impossible  to have `param_name not equal to "active"`. So `param_name="widgetCampaignName"` is useless.

Comment: It is true only in case when `widget_uid` is UNIQUE in `widget_config_value` table.

Comment: @Vicky. [Igor]{http://stackoverflow.com/users/883286/igor} is right. But column name having `_uid` make me issume that it is `UNIQUE ID`

Comment: @Igor . You are right. But column name with `_uid` in it make me assume that it is UNIQUE Key.

Comment: It often happens when scripts for tables and test data were not provided :)